# Enable json serialization of Multimap in Spring Boot Project

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, spring-boot, guava

I want to serialize some google guava Multimap in a spring boot application.

```
public class SomeDTO {
    @JsonProperty
    Multimap<A, B> prop = HashMultimap.create();
}
```

Without using a customized jackson serializer, I get some result like

```
{
   "prop ":
   {
       "empty": false
   }
}
```

Which is definitley not what I seek to get.  I thought of something like:

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "key0": [
      {
        "prop0": 2,
        "prop1": 4
      },
      {
        "prop0": 5,
        "prop1": 6
      }
    ],
    "key1": [
      {
        "prop0": 23,
        "prop1": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

to the pom.xml seems not sufficient... However, I'm just starting with this whole spring // pivotal universe, so I guess I miss something obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution i came up with is simply adding a `@Bean` to my main `@Configuration`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule;
// More-obvious imports missing

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper customizeJacksonConfiguration() {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
        return om;
    }
}
```

Afaik, the `ObjectMapper` Bean approach has one drawback: Everytime an ObjectMapper is created this way, all previous configuration gets thrown away.

If you want to *add a module* to jackson - instead of overriding previous configuration, this approach is better:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule;
// More-obvious imports missing

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Module guavaModule() {
        return new GuavaModule();
    }
}
```

Comment: Imo, a new answer would have been favourable ;) I actually forgot about this question. But yes, you are totally right. Using a Module does not mess up the whole spring application where it relies on the objectmapper. @neil

Comment: For those wondering what dependency is needed: [jackson-datatype-guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-guava)