# Configuring auto-serialization of Guava Multimap with Spring Boot when the `SpringBootApplication` impelments `WebMvcConfigurer`

Tags: spring-boot, guava, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I have the following `SpringBootApplication`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class RestServer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestServer.class, args);
  }
}
```

And I would like Guava's `Multimap` get automatically serialized to JSON.

So I have this code in one of my classes, where all other fields are successfully serialized to JSON:

```
@JsonProperty("multimap_test")
public Multimap<Instrument, AdjustedLimitOrder> getMultimap() {
  return someMultiMap;
}
```

But the returned JSON field looks like this:

```
"multimap_test": {
  "empty": false
}
```

Do I have to specify a deserializer on the field?

Using this doesn't work because there is no default constructor:

```
@JsonProperty("multimap_test")
public Multimap<Instrument, AdjustedLimitOrder> getMultimap() {
  return someMultimap;
}
```

*Note that my example is implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`.*

Here is a list of links of instructions that didn't seem conclusive on how to do this, because they discuss the case when the `SpringBootApplication` implements `SpringBootServletInitializer` or `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` (which is deprecated).

- http://gdpotter.com/2017/05/24/custom-spring-mvc-jackson/
- [Enable json serialization of Multimap in Spring Boot Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893215/enable-json-serialization-of-multimap-in-spring-boot-project)

**How can Guava's `Multimap` get automatically serialized?**

Answer (score 4):

The [spring boot MVC auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) already configures to use Jackson to input/output JSON if Jackson is found in classpath. But the configured Jackson by default will not support Guava `Multimap`, you have to register `GuavaModule` to the Jackson `ObjectMapper` in order to support it (see [docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/tree/master/guava#registering-module)).

From the `JacksonAutoConfiguration` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html) , it will auto-register `GuavaModule` to the `ObjectMapper` if we declare it as a bean. So in order to serialize/desearialize `Multimap` , you have to

1. Add Jackson 's Guava module to `pom.xml` :

   ```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Declare a `GuavaModule` bean in `@SpringBootApplication` :

   ```
     @Bean
     public Module guavaModule() {
         return new GuavaModule();
     }
   ```

And it is done . `WebMvcConfigurer` / `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is intended for customizing spring boot MVC default settings . You don't need to customize it for your case as Spring MVC already work with Jackson to input/output JSON out of the box . What you need to do is to configure Jackson but not configure spring boot MVC . So, it does not matter whether `SpringBootApplication` implement or not implement `WebMvcConfigurer`/`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` if you just want to auto-serialise `Multimap`.

Comment: I added that exact function definition for `public Module guavaModule()` to the `SpringBootApplication`, but IntelliJ IDEA says the function is unused, but it executes when I put a breakpoint on it. However, the `Multimap` just gets serialized as `"multimap_test": { "empty": false }` and no more information. I updated my question with more info.

Comment: Put the breakpoint at `JacksonAutoConfiguration#configureModules(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder)` ,  the `GuavaModule` is registered in here.

Comment: What is that `@JsonSerialize(using = MultimapSerializer)` ? Try to remove it to see what happen

Comment: When I put that breakpoint, I can see `GuavaModule@11806` in the `builder.modulesToInstall(moduleBeans.toArray...)` call. And I removed that `@JsonSerialize` annotation, but it's still serializing with only `"empty": false`.

Comment: I also put breakpoints in all of the `serialize*()` functions in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.ser.MultimapSerializer`, and none of them are triggered.

Comment: Then not sure. I do not have such problems (I am using the spring boot MVC default settings plus my suggested changes) Can you try to simply put some dummy data to a  `Multimap<Integer,String>` and then return it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187767/discussion-between-neil-and-ken-chan).