# Using a MultiMap on spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, guava, multimap

I have the following payload:

```
{
    "KeyA": "ValueA",
    "KeyB": "ValueB",
    "KeyC": "ValueC"
    ...
    "KeyZ": "ValueZ"
}
```

That I am able to parse properly in a spring boot controller with:

```
@PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Object> createABC(
      @RequestBody final Map<MyDTO, MyDTO> map
  ) {
```

For the sake of brevity, consider `MyDTO` as:

```
@Data
@ToString(includeFieldNames=false)
public class MyDTO implements Comparable<MyDTO> {
  private final String name;
```

The problem is:

I can have duplicated keys on the input:

```
{
    "KeyA": "ValueA",
    "KeyA": "ValueA.1",
    ...
}
```

Which then gets deduplicated by the native Java Map implementation - only the second key gets saved and I am okay with that. I found out [Guava Multimap](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-multimap) that would allow me to do it. This would allow me to accept a map with duplicates and let me execute the custom logic on the controller/service layer.

The problem is that I can't find how to make spring boot parse this map in the controller without reformatting the request, I would like to keep it as it is. I was able to add the [Object Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893215/enable-json-serialization-of-multimap-in-spring-boot-project) but I am failing to be able to receive this map from the request at the controller and use it.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The problem is that I can't find how to make spring boot parse this map in the controller without reformatting the request
```

I'm not sure what you meant by this, but I assume that you are sending the request like this :

[image]

If you want to use `com.google.common.collect.Multimap`
there is no other way to send a request.

If you want to send a request in the form you mentioned in the question (withot **[]** brackets), as far as I can see, you have two options:

1. Use `org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap` with custom deserilizer;

Here is how your custom deserilizer should look like:

```
import com.example.demo.dto.MyDTO;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;

import java.io.IOException;

class MultiValuedMapJsonDeerializer extends JsonDeserializer<MultiValuedMap> {

    @Override
    public MultiValuedMap deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        MultiValuedMap<MyDTO, MyDTO> myDTOMyDTOMultiValuedMap = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
        if (jp.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            throw new IOException("invalid start marker");
        }

        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            String fieldname = jp.getCurrentName();
            jp.nextToken();
            String value = jp.getText();
            MyDTO key = new MyDTO(fieldname);
            MyDTO myDTO = new MyDTO(value);
            myDTOMyDTOMultiValuedMap.put(key, myDTO);
        }
        jp.close();

        return myDTOMyDTOMultiValuedMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<MultiValuedMap> handledType() {
        return MultiValuedMap.class;
    }
}
```

Here is how endpoint shoud look like:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public void createABC(@RequestBody final MultiValuedMap<MyDTO, MyDTO> map) {
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

When you hit this endpoint, you should see output like this:

```
{MyDTO(keyB)=[MyDTO(B)], MyDTO(keyC)=[MyDTO(C), MyDTO(D)], MyDTO(keyA)=[MyDTO(A)]}
```

2. Use `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap`

If you want to use this class, you shoud send your request body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Here is an example from Postman:

[image]

And finally, if you decide to use this option here is an example how controller method should look like:

```
@PostMapping("/multiValueMap")
    public void multiValueMap(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<MyDTO, MyDTO> multiValueMap) {
        System.out.println(multiValueMap);
       
    }
```

Using this approach, you should see output like this:

```
{KeyB=[b], KeyA=[a, c]}
```

Comment: Hi Nemanja, spot on mate, thanks a lot for the time elaborating on the answer! Your approach with the MultiValuedMap and the Deserializer solved the problem gracefully although I had to change the library from Guava's to Apache's. I couldn't make it work with Guava's, given I had a bit of preference for it.

Comment: I still don't get why `com.google.common.collect.Multimap` requires you to send the data as `"KeyA": [ "ValueA" ]` since the underlying DTO just requires a string parameter.

Comment: @NeillLima I'm glad to hear that this helped you :) About second comment, honestly I also don't understand why [] are required when you send just one value for the key.. But unfortunetly, that's how it work..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've successfully added [`GuavaModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatypes-collections/javadoc/guava/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/guava/GuavaModule.html) to Jackson's configuration, so you're only missing an additional Spring [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.message-converters) for Jackson as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.message-converters). In your case it's [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html), ex.:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

(Or use constructor with explicit `ObjectMapper` for the custom converter if necessary, please consult the documentation.)